# Missing an Azure Table Storage LoggingHandler for EHAB in EnterpriseLibrary 6.0

Tags: azure, enterprise-library, azure-table-storage

The Exception Handling Application Block enables me to log exception information using the Logging Application Block. There a listeners for database, windows eventlog, msmq, etc... but there is **no listener available to log the exception into the azure table storage**.

I could configure the LoggingHandler to log into the eventlog and use the DiagnosticMonitor to transfer my logs into the table storage every 1 minute. But this sounds awkward to me.

Do I have to write a custom logging handler which logs to the Azure table storage for myself? Or **did I missed something?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at the patterns & practices – Enterprise Library official web site (https://entlib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=EntLib6ReleaseNotes) and I could not find a way to this with EHAB.

Maybe you need switch to Semantic Logging Application Block (SLAB). This one gives you the ability to persist in windows azure tables and others data sources too:

http://convective.wordpress.com/2013/08/12/semantic-logging-application-block-slab/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already use the SLAB for logging in my application. Unfortunately, it is doesn't work with the EHAB (which can only log using the Logging Application block).

Comment: @jisaak: you can write your own IExceptionHandler that works with Semantic Logging.  See http://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/444886 for an example.